# How to find the Android App lifecycle activity?

Tags: android, logcat

I am trying to perform the digital forensics experiment in my Android phone. I would like to know how to get the common chatting app lifecycle log, like Discord, Facebook Messenger or WhatsApp. I want to find the exact time each of the lifecycle methods is called for each app, such as `onCreate()`, `onStart()`, `onStop()`, etc.
I tried looking up in data/system/usagestats folder, but I was only able to   find the records for `onPause()` and `onResume()` in the usagestats folder.

I cannot find the other activities, like `onStart()`, `onCreate()`, `onStop()` and `onDestory()`.
I also checked the logcat, but the log seems did not record these information regarding lifecycle methods.
Does anyone know where I can find a detailed records regarding the time each lifecycle methods is called?

Comment: What do you mean by "forensics"?

Comment: What I'm trying to say is the experiment of extracting data from Android phones. I would like to know how to get the common chatting app lifecycle log, like Discord.

Comment: How does Discord do?

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand your question. Do you mean what Discord is use for? It's a chat app.